# C++ retro newbie: address references

Tags: c++, pointers, null

So, after taking 20 years off from C++, I have gotten back into it.  I for the life of me cannot wrap my head around this issue.  I am working with [at work] classes were I pass address references, rather than pointer references.  This little foo() example below, why cannot I not return NULL or nullptr?  What rule am I violating that I am forgetting?

```
int& foo(int &i)
{
  if (i > 10)
  {
    // or return nullptr;
    return NULL;
  }
  return i;
}
```

Comment: You're violating the rule that references can't be NULL.

Comment: You can't return `nullptr` because it's of pointer type, but `int&` declares the return type to be of reference type.

Comment: C++ has no notion of "address". Nor "pointer references", at least in the way you seem to mean it. I suggest you read up on the difference between pointers and references.

Comment: @Sneftel: I'd say a "pointer reference" is just a colloquial name for a "reference to a pointer", isn't it?

Comment: I have no idea what "address references" and "pointer references" are. What book are you using? C++ as a standardised language hasn't even existed for 20 years, y'know... You should pretend that you've never even heard of C++ and read a C++ book to learn the language before asking silly questions!

Comment: @ChristianHackl As I mentioned, not the way the OP seems to mean it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why cannot I not return NULL or nullptr?

Because you have declared the function to return a **reference** to an int. References must always "point" to an actual `int` that exists. A `nullptr` is therefore not a valid value. (A null pointer is not convertible to a reference to int, it's only convertible to a **pointer** to int.)

**Solution 1:**

Declare the function to return a pointer to an int:

```
int* foo(int &i)
{
  if (i > 10)
  {
    return nullptr; // or NULL, or 0. (Since NULL is a macro expanding to `0` or `nullptr` anyway.)
  }
  return &i; // Return the address of i, aka a pointer to i.
}
```

---

**Solution 2:**

Declare an int value that is semantically identical to returning a null value.

```
int& foo(int &i)
{
  static int nullValue = 0;
  if (i > 10)
  {
    // or return nullptr;
    return nullValue;
  }
  return i;
}
```

Now every time `i > 10` is true, the function will return a reference to the static local variable which is equal to `0` (you can change the actual value if needed).

Of course, if `return i` returns the a value identical to `nullValue`, then the function caller can't know whether the function returned a reference to the `nullValue` or some actual value `i`.

Comment: Thanks for this.  After reading both the first and second answer I *understand* what I was doing wrong.  This helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as "address references". There are "references", and they are different from pointers. C++ references are a very powerful language feature absent from many other languages (e.g. C or Java).

A reference is best pictured as a different name for an existing object. Or better yet, as the object itself. **A reference is the object.**

That's not at all like a pointer. A pointer *is itself an object* which happens to point to something else (or to nothing).

> They do it for performance reasons.

No, they don't. If they said this, then it doesn't make sense. You don't use references for performance (at least not non-const references), you use them for correctness.

> ```
> int& foo(int &i)
> {
>   if (i > 10)
>   {
>     // or return nullptr;
>     return NULL;
>   }
>   return i;
> }
> ```

There is no such thing as "null references". Remember, a reference is the object. So what your `foo` function here returns is actually the object itself. Not a pointer to it, not its address, but the object itself.

And what object would `NULL` or `nullptr` be? It doesn't make sense. There cannot be an object which is nothing.

If you need to be able to have a special "nothing" state in your business logic, then you can use something like [`boost::optional`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html). Or perhaps you really want a pointer, after all. It depends.

> rather than pointer references.

Pointer references exist, but they are not related to your example.

Here is a pointer reference:

```
int main()
{
    int x = 0;
    int* ptr = &x;
    int*& y = ptr; // "y" is now a different name for "ptr"
}
```

Comment: You are clearly a very smart individual.  Thanks for sharing your answer with me.

Answer (score 1):

You might [find this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-a-pointer-variable-and-a-reference-variable-in#57492) answer insightful.

**Short answer:** In C++ a reference can never be `NULL` (or any version of `NULL` like `nullptr`) because it must always be safe to de-reference.

Comment: This makes perfect sense.  Thanks for the analogy.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ NULL is implementation defined but usually it is just integer:

```
#define NULL 0
```

or

`#define NULL nullptr`   // since C++11

In both cases the error is type mismatch:

```
error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'int&'
       from an rvalue of type 'int'
       #define NULL 0
                    ^
```

Comment: Thanks for this. After reading both the first and second answer I understand what I was doing wrong. This helped me a lot.

Comment: Even worse,  if `NULL` is defined as `0`, then `return NULL` will return a reference to a *local variable* which will be destroyed when the function exits.

Comment: @zenith not true, if #define NULL 0 it doesn't compile, and the error thrown is as I pasted. It is so to prevent from mistake that you mentioned.

Comment: @AB_ You are right, my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Null references are not allowed - "A reference shall be initialized to refer to a valid object or function. [Note: in particular, a null reference cannot exist in a well-defined program, because the only way to create such a reference would be to bind it to the “object” obtained by dereferencing a null pointer, which causes undefined behavior. As described in 9.6, a reference cannot be bound directly to a bitfield. ]".    Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_%28C%2B%2B%29